# Need help aligning list number <ol>

Tags: html

How do I adjust this properly so that the numbers 1. are not off to the left but in the center with the rest of my list? Thank you in advance! Using Chrome not sure if that matters I am new.

```
<ol align="center">
   <li><br>Unique</li>
    <li><br>Bold/Straightforward</li>
     <li><br>Funny</li>
      <li><br>Spontanious</li>
       <li><br>Unpredictable</li>
        <li><br>Creative</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: `list-style-position:inside;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/paKGq/) what you want?

**HTML:**

```
<ol>
    <li><br />Unique</li>
    <li><br />Bold/Straightforward</li>
    <li><br />Funny</li>
    <li><br />Spontaneous</li> <!-- fixed typo here -->
    <li><br />Unpredictable</li>
    <li><br />Creative</li>
</ol>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Use CSS to center */    
li { text-align: center; list-style-position: inside; }
```